# JasperServer Error - Unable to get next record

Tags: java, sql, jasper-reports, jasperserver

I have a very simple report that runs perfectly on in iReports (4.5.0) on my workstation. When I upload it JasperServer CE  (4.5.0) I get the following error.

```
1 - Unable to get next record. 
java.lang.Exception: 1 - Unable to get next record.
at com.jaspersoft.ireport.jasperserver.ws.WSClient.runReport(WSClient.java:403)
at com.jaspersoft.ireport.jasperserver.ws.WSClient.runReport(WSClient.java:320)
at com.jaspersoft.ireport.jasperserver.ReportRunner.run(ReportRunner.java:70)
at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Task.run(RequestProcessor.java:572)
at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Processor.run(RequestProcessor.java:997)
```

There are other much more complex queries and reports that are running on the JasperServer without problem. The database system is Basis/Pro5 running BBJ (Business Basic Java). I am connected to the database in iReports and JasperServer using the same native JDBC Basis driver (BBjJDBS.jar). JasperServer is running on the same RHEL box as the BBj database. Jasper server is installed as a bundle using both the built in DB and Tomcat. No other known conflicts exist.

The following single table query is designed to get the sum totals of a transaction for a given month. The report has one detail section which just prints the query output.

```
SELECT
    Month(INHI.TRANSACTION_DATE) AS TransMonth,
    admin.INHI.ITEM_ID,
    admin.INHI.TRANSACTION_TYPE,
    SUM(admin.INHI.TRANS_QUANTITY) as TransQty
FROM
    admin.INHI
WHERE
    admin.INHI.ITEM_ID = 'R-CBSH-3300'
AND (
        admin.INHI.TRANSACTION_TYPE = 'B2'
    OR  admin.INHI.TRANSACTION_TYPE = 'P1')
AND admin.INHI.TRANSACTION_DATE BETWEEN '2012-01-01' AND '2012-03-31'
GROUP BY
    Month(INHI.TRANSACTION_DATE),
    admin.INHI.ITEM_ID,
    admin.INHI.TRANSACTION_TYPE
Order By
admin.INHI.TRANSACTION_TYPE
```

I have looked all over to try and find additional trouble shooting tips and have ran out of options to try.  Any guidance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I was able to get an extended error from the JasperServer web interface which lead me to an Date/Time issue. The crux of the whole problem was the "Order By" clause. Once I removed the order by the query worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can also get this error if you pass a closed result set as the data source for the report.

In my case I passed the `JasperReportBuilder` object around and somewhere I (prematurely) closed the `Connection` object that the result set was bound to.